# NSNumber doubleValue returns NaN

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

As the screenshot below shows, `nsdt`'s value is approximately 0.033, but the `doubleValue` method returned NaN. Why is it not returning 0.033?

```
-(void) updateWithDTNSTime:(NSNumber*) nsdt;
{
    double dt = [nsdt doubleValue];

    if(isnan(dt))
    {
        printf("nan\n");
    }

    [self updateWithDTime:dt];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"nsdt = %@", nsdt);`

Comment: Where do you get that number from?

Comment: @zneak -- He's looking at the debugger, a screen image of which is behind "Code Picture Link" above.

Comment: @Hot Licks, I saw the picture. I meant to see where/how the NSNumber instance is created.

Comment: Unfortunately, the debugger is not all that reliable, so I'd prefer to see the nsdt `description` printed.

Comment: Running your posted code in the app delegate and passing it a NSNumber containing a number didn't result in NaN. There's probably something wrong with the passed NSNumber as the method body seems okay. As Hot Licks said, log the description of nsdt. It _should_ log the double value of the NSNumber. Can we see the code that calls this method?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I am having basically the same exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code creating nsdt variable. It should be like that:

```
nsdt - [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.033];
```

You will have 0 if your code looks like this:

```
int x = 0.033;
NSNumber *test = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:x];
double y = [test doubleValue];
NSLog(@"y= %f", y);
```